# Definition of a tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Today we defined a tangent space similar to the description here:

[enter link description here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Definition_as_velocities_of_curves)

My problem is the following: Why do we need to refer to charts in this case? I mean, would it not be sufficient to say that a tangent space is given by all the tangent vectors of differentiable curves at a particular point on this manifold? I mean, if it is possible to put this manifold in a huge $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it would be also pretty sure how one would add two tangent vectors and so on, so this would clearly define nice vector space. I do not see the need that they are referring to charts in this case. Could anybody explain to me, why this idea is still necessary though?

Comment: Good question! But, how are you going to define the tangent vectors to your curves intrinsically?

Comment: i also considered this, but wikipedia says that the curves are differentiable. this should mean, that it is possible to say what a tangent vector is or am I wrong?

Comment: Differentiability has a natural implicit definition on smooth manifolds: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Differentiable_functions. No embedding in Euclidean space is involved in this definition.

Comment: You can absolutely talk of the tangent vector of a curve, or of a differential map between manifolds. However, these things are defined locally, using charts. For instance, the "implicit" definition that Sean links to still refers to charts. One pulls things back to $\mathbf R^n$ using a chart, does whatever needs to be done in $\mathbf R^n$, and then pushes the result back to the manifold. Of course, the end result is independent of the chosen chart, but a *choice* of chart is still required.